# React Native Bottom tabs navigator. tabBarButton: () => {} option is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a question. When I use Tab navigator with separate Tab.Screen I should have an option tabBarButton as stated [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarbutton). But when I try to use it, it throws an error.

Here is the code:

```
<Tab.Screen
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return (
          <TabIcon
            focused={focused}
            icon={icons.trade}
            isTrade
            label='Trade'
          />
        );
      },
      tabBarButton: (props) => {
        <TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => console.log('wa')}>
          <Text>Touch</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>;
      },
    }}
    name='Trade'
    component={Home}
  />
```

and here stack error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RC4X.jpg)

The Source that is written useFonts.js is sometimes changing. I don't think this file is causing errors. when I remove tabBarButton option, it functions properly.

By the way, I am using EXPO for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the component in the `tabBarButton` callback. This can be done in two ways:

By adding a `return` statement:

```js
    tabBarButton: (props) => {
        return <TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => console.log('wa')}>
          <Text>Touch</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>;
      },
```

or removing the brackets of the callback and make it an implicit return:

```js
    tabBarButton: (props) => <TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => console.log('wa')}>
          <Text>Touch</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>,
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the promlem.  I forgot to return a React.Component

Comment: Great! Could you mark this answer as the solution by using the checkmark onder the vote arrows if this has helped you?